# Using an anchor href in a javascript onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, href

I have an href that I would like to use with in an onclick method on the same anchor.

Here's an anchor:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="VideoTrackNLog('Best Practices 3','www.google.com');"><img alt="Best Practice 3"      src="timg/BestPractice3.jpg" style="width: 236px; height: 157px" /> </a></td>
```

and here's the code the onclick is using:

```
function VideoTrackNLog(videoname, filename, file) {
        frmVideoTrackNLog.videoname.value = videoname;
        frmVideoTrackNLog.nextpagename.value = filename;
        frmVideoTrackNLog.submit();
        window.open(file,'Video','height=200,width=200,left=190,top=110,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes');
}
```

The idea is to move the URL in the href to the third parameter in the function. Is there any way this would be possible?

Comment: Can't you just leave the href blank and move the URL to be a function parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
VideoTrackNLog('Best Practices 3','www.google.com', this.href);
```

Comment: Yep, but it would be better if you could also **explain** it.

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize there was much to explain here. You could pass any of the attributes from the element into the events tied to the element such as this.href, this.id, etc. Heck, you can even pass the element itself.

Comment: For someone who doesn't know JS event handlers, it would be very helpful to explain that `this` references the element the handler is bound to and since the element is a link, it has an `href` property containing the URL. There is also a nice article that explains inline event handlers: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html.

Answer (score 0):

Leave the `href` blank and move the URL to be a function parameter:

```
<a href=# onclick="VideoTrackNLog('Best Practices 3','www.google.com', 'http://www.google.com');">
    <img alt="Best Practice 3" src="timg/BestPractice3.jpg" style="width: 236px; height: 157px" />
</a>
```